# PHP script being interrupted at random time

Tags: php

I have a php script that does a lot of stuff, produces a lot of output and can take a few minutes to complete.

I have already placed a set_time_limit(999999) at the beginning.

Before that, it obviously exceeded the time limit of 30 seconds and got interrupted. When that happened, a fatal error was logged indicating just that.

Now, from the browser I call that script, I observe as the browser receive the output from the script almost in real time, but at a random point, the script just is interrupted. It does *not* exceed the time limit (obviously), and NO ERROR at all is logged. Actually, if I try it a second time it gets interrupted at a different point.

The question is, if no error is encountered, and the time limit is not reached, what else can cause the script to be interrupted? Perhaps a disconnection from the client (browser) due to timeout? (not timeout waiting for data, though, as data is constantly being output). Perhaps the browser may have a maximum size for an html page?

But if it's one of these two cases, how comes this is not logged as an error?

Comment: If the client has a low quality connection, you may experience these kinds of disruptions. I am experiencing those on my end sometimes.

Comment: what about your code? where is your code? are you connecting to database in your script? are you trying to execute script from command line? add your code and explain about script.

Comment: It's not the code. When the code has fatal errors, they get logged; when it has non-fatal errors, they are handled by the yii framework which I'm using and an error page is displayed. Neither is the case; also, an error in the code would break the script always at the same point. It's definitely as @Truth says; what I don't understand is why PHP doesn't log an error message in the error log in those cases....

Answer (score 0):

When the script reaches the time limit, a fatal error is thrown, so if you are not seeing any error, this shouldn't be the cause (Make sur that error reporting is activated, either set it in the script or in the php.ini file).

If you want to desactivate time limit use this instead :

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Without more informations, we can't be of much help unfortunately.